# Custom logback Converter in Play framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, logback

I'm trying to add a custom converter(`logging.logback.SchemaNameConverter`) to logback configuration, the converter makes use of a `Http.Context`. The converter is placed inside play module.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: logging.logback.SchemaNameConverter
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at controllers.Application.list3(Application.java:106)
        at router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$9$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(Routes.scala:349)
        at router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$9$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(Routes.scala:349)
        at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$$anon$4.resultCall(HandlerInvoker.scala:157)
        at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$$anon$4.resultCall(HandlerInvoker.scala:156)
        at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$JavaActionInvokerFactory$$anon$14$$anon$3$$anon$1.invocation(HandlerInvoker.scala:136)
        at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$1.call(JavaAction.scala:73)
        at ActionCreator$1.call(ActionCreator.java:25)
        at org.pac4j.play.java.SecureAction.lambda$null$1(SecureAction.java:106)
        at org.pac4j.core.engine.DefaultSecurityLogic.perform(DefaultSecurityLogic.java:139)
        at org.pac4j.play.java.SecureAction.lambda$internalCall$2(SecureAction.java:101)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
        at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext$$anon$2.run(HttpExecutionContext.scala:56)
        at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:39)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:415)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

From my initial diagnosis, it looks like the problem is with the classloaders. The main application is using `ReloadableClassLoader(v1){file:.../target/scala-2.11/classes/}` to load the classes application where as logback is using `PlayDependencyClassLoader` to load its dependencies. Since the converter class is within the application it is not found by the `PlayDependencyClassLoader` loader.

Comment: Which version of Play are you using?

Comment: @mkurz it is `2.5.12`